# Include Python libraries in composer.json for Heroku

Tags: python, php, heroku, composer-php

I'm trying to deploying an app with Heroku via PHP, but it runs a Python script that is dependent on Python libraries to run (e.g. `numpy`).

How would I go about including this dependency in a `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).

1. Configure your application to use [the official PHP buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php):

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
   ```
2. Add [the official Python buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python):

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python
   ```

   Running `heroku buildpacks` should show the Python buildpack first and the PHP one second.

   > The last buildpack in the list will be used to determine the [process types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) for the application. Any process types defined from earlier buildpacks will be ignored.
3. Make sure you have a `composer.json` that defines your PHP dependencies in the root of your repository for your PHP buildpack.
4. Make sure you have either a `requirements.txt` file (if you want to use `pip`) or a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` (if you want to use Pipenv) that defines your Python dependencies in the root of your repository for your Python buildpack.

   It's also a good idea to specify [the supported Python version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version) that you wish to use. If you are using Pipenv, this information can be included in your `Pipfile`. If you are using `pip` you can use [a `runtime.txt` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) in the root of your repository.

The next time you deploy you should see your Python dependencies get installed first, followed by your PHP dependencies.